# How to get Myatt achievment in 'macdows 95'?

Tags: achievements, macdows-95

I've played the game 'macdows 95' from Humble Bundle trove and I achieved everything except Myatt - I didn't find him and he didn't find me.

If anyone knows how to earn this achievement, please share

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this was the hardest one for me as well...You really need to think outside the box! You need to close the game, open it again and where you would put the password to log in, you have to put the right numbers but in the wrong places! I can't remember the password, but if it was 123, you would need to write 312! Right numbers, wrong places! Hope I helped!

Comment: My password is 378 so I tried to mix it up before but nothing
Now I tried all 8XX, 7XX, 3XX (800, 801, 802..)  combinations still nothing :( . If you can post a picture of the completed Myatt I'll really appreciate it

Comment: @Flamerion Please try 783 or 837.